# search for element in list and replace it by multiple items

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way to search through the given list `['a', 'b', 'c']` for the element `b` replace it and insert multiple items `b1, b2, b3` so that the list finally reads as `['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']`

Comment: What should happen if `b` is present more than once?

Comment: in my particular case its guaranteed that the items are unique

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using slice notation:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> i = lst.index('b') # This raises ValueError if there's no 'b' in the list.
>>> lst[i:i+1] = 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'
>>> lst
['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']
```

**NOTE** This changes only the first matching item.

Comment: @SteveP., See [*Lists* section from Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: @SteveP., Because the `list.__setitem__ with slice object argument` is implemented that way. See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a3bdbe220f8a/Objects/listobject.c#l579

Answer (score 6):

Alternate approach: Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a = [b if x=='b' else [x] for x in a] 
>>> a
['a', ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], 'c']
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']
>>>
```

Comment: To support a general case, single elements must be made iterable: `...else [x] for x in a`.

Comment: Try `a = ['aaa', 'b', 'ccc']`, and you will see why @thg435 suggest `[x]`. (BTW, string objects are iterable.)

Answer (score 2):

I think just using list comprehensions is cleaner & more robust:

```py
b_vals = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
given_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

expansions = (b_vals if e == 'b' else [e] for e in given_list)
expanded = [v for vals in expansions for v in vals]
# => ['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']
```

no imports, no mutation, no dealing with indexes, doesn't error if `'b'` doesn't exist.