# replace multiple strings in a list with a single string by knowing the index

Tags: python, string, list

I want to replace multiple strings in a list with a single string by knowing the index. Of course I looked at this question: [search for element in list and replace it by multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499312/search-for-element-in-list-and-replace-it-by-multiple-items) But for my case it is inverse, suppose I have a list as follow:

```
lst = ['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']
```

I know that I have a term:

```
term = 'b1' + ' b2' + ' b3'
```

I also know the starting index and the length of that term

```
lst[1:1+len(term)] = "<term>" + term + "</term>"
```

I got this result:

```
['a', '<', 't', 'e', 'r', 'm', '>', 'b', '1', ' ', 'b', '2', ' ', 'b', '3', '<', '/', 't', 'e', 'r', 'm', '>']
```

However, my expected output:

```
['a', '<term>b1 b2 b3</term>', 'c']
```

How can I adjust this to get the desired output?

Comment: That is because you change a list. But why is your expected output ending with an 'b'? While len(term) is long (it is in fact 8, all the characters). Therefore it will overwrite your whole list.

Comment: Is the last index of your expected output right? 'b'? Shouldn't it be 'c'?

Comment: edited the question sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Edit your code such that you insert a list in `lst[1:-1]`:

```py
lst = ['a', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c']
term = 'b1' + ' b2' + ' b3'
lst[1:-1] = ["<term>" + term + "</term>"]
print(lst)
>> ['a', '<term>b1 b2 b3</term>', 'c']
```

As you can see, I also changed the index from `lst[1:len(term)+1]` to `lst[1:-1]`, such that you keep the first and last terms.

Comment: Good. But I’d shoot for `f"<term>{lst[idx]}+{lst[idx+1] +{lst[idx+2]</term>"`.  With idx at 1. i.e. less hardcoding.  But your answer’s still nearly the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `lst` and `term` list, join the strings into a single string: `term_string = "<term>" + " ".join(term) + "</term>"`

Then slice to replace the strings with the joined string: `lst[1:1+len(term)] = [term_string]`

Comment: In the question `term` is a string, but I guess it should be a list as assumed in this answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, read too quickly. Yes, define term as a list to use `.join(...)`: `term = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']`!